# Android CredentialManager: GetCredentialResponse error returned from framework

Tags: android, kotlin, w3c, credential-manager, passkey

I'm testing the abilities of the Android Credential Manager APIs to work with passkeys over W3C standards.
While everything is set up and works I'm getting the following errors **inconsistently** :

1. While registering a new passkey sometimes (about 10% of the tries) I'm getting an exception from CredentialManager:
   `CreatePublicKeyCredentialDomException: The incoming request cannot be validated`
   The officials say:
   `The app's package ID is not registered with your server. Validate this in your server-side integration.`
   but it is set-up and 9 out of 10 calls succeed what proves that it is working.
2. While getting passkey from the CredentialManager API **inconsistently** the APIs prompts me to scan QR with other device (I assume it cannot retrieve my passkey on current device) and the only output I can get from it is:
    `GetCredentialResponse error returned from framework`

I've tried to find the answers for days, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with a similar issue and i was use `site.glitch.me` as google code lab  and i use it as `relying party` for testing.

but after i make my `assetlinks.json` and deploy it on my server everything works fine.

Comment: exactly my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a similar issue where the `getCrendentials()` request for passkeys failed most of the time.

Turned out that the `challenge` payload that is sent with the request was not properly base-64 encoded.
After checking the device logs (without any filter) I found
the CredentialManager was logging `bad base-64`
The challenge was lacking URL-safe encoding therefore most of the challenge payloads where corrupted, resulting in those failures.